# Problem Compiling in VS 2005 after installing microsoft platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2005, sdk, compilation

As the title suggests I'm having a problem compiling MFC based applications, this problem started immediately after installing the windows server 2003 platform SDK and now even when I try to compile a new MFC project I get the following errors:

> c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(141) : error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before identifier 'HwndMSWheel'
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(141) : error
>   C2433: 'HWND' : 'inline' not permitted
>   on data declarations
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(141) : error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(142) : error
>   C2065: 'PUINT' : undeclared identifier
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(142) : error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ')'
>   before identifier
>   'puiMsh_MsgMouseWheel'
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(142) : error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(147) : error
>   C2059: syntax error : ')'
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(148) : error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before '{'
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\zmouse.h(148) : error
>   C2447: '{' : missing function header
>   (old-style formal list?)
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\commctrl.h(29) : error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before identifier 'HRESULT'
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\commctrl.h(29) : error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\commctrl.h(29) : error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int
>   assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\prsht.h(97) : error C2065:
>   'CALLBACK' : undeclared identifier
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\prsht.h(97) : error C2065:
>   'LPFNPSPCALLBACKA' : undeclared
>   identifier
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\prsht.h(97) : error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed.
>   Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft platform
>   sdk\include\prsht.h(97) : fatal error
>   C1903: unable to recover from previous
>   error(s); stopping compilation

in some cases I solved the problem by including windows.h and defining WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN at the top of stdafx.h. However for large projects that uses static and dynamic linking to other libraries the proposed solution did not work. I'm not really sure why this is happening as I've also tried to reinstall the platform SDK to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to #include windows.h before zmouse.h